# Read pdf via native Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

I'm want to read pdf on client and show some preview or full pdf. I saw many interesting plugins like: Mozilla pdf.js, pdfObject, viewerjs  etc.

That's great but I'm really don't understand how it works on client without server. How we can get access to file and parse it on client. I looking on mdn javascript API and found nothing.

Maybe I missed something? Please, explain me algoritm and what native JS API I can use for it. 
Many thanks for any help.

Comment: The javascript library does not directly access a file on the server (it obviously can't), but it handles a PDF document requested from the server (note: a document, not a file). So typically a URL is requested that retrieves a PDF document, that document then is displayed on the client side inside an `<iframe>` by means of the javascript library.

Comment: Thanks for Answering Arkasha. So if I understand correctly - we receive document and should place him into iframe and after that we can easilly handle this document data (text/images etc.). Correct?  
But how we can make preview  from this document?

Comment: You don't make a preview and you don't handle document elements separately. You simply display the document inside an iframe. A preview does not really make sense, since you have to download the full document anyway. If you want a real preview to save bandwidth, then create an image with low resolution on the server side, typically done on-the-fly, so as a service per request.

Comment: Many thanks for your help Arkascha!